# measuring application with multiple threads accessing the same array

Tags: c#

Hellow everybody,

I am creating an application to automate measurements.

So I have a measuring device that is controlled by 'background worker 1'. This background worker sends commands to let the device measure and then receives measured values ​​back. These measured values ​​are then stored in a 2D array. This is a device that sometimes has to measure for hours/days without being interrupted. (Also, the time between measurements should always be the same.)
But to ensure that data is not lost because of a power failure, I would like to save the values ​​every 10 minutes to a file (CSV-format). Saving to a file would be done via backgroundworker 2.

My question to you is: Is it possible to continuously write to an array (via backgroundworker1) and then read from the same array (via backgroundworker2)?

Comment: Why would you need to read the whole array? If you have a Text file, you can just append rows. Doing it async, you wouldn't even need a second BGW.

Comment: @Fildor I have to write every time on the end of a line the new data. Here you can choose to first read in the file again and then add the new data. Or you can just overwrite the entire file (what is faster).

Comment: No. You can happily append to a Textfile without reading in the whole thing, if you know what data is "new". Which you obviously do know.

Comment: ^^ See [File.AppendText(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I don’t want to append on the end of the file, but on the end of each line in the file. And for that you have to read first that line. Or am I completely wrong?
Before measuring data ‘z’:
`data_x1, data_y1 \n
data_x2, data_y2 \n
data_x3, data_y3`

After measuring data ‘z’:
`data_x1, data_y1, data_z1 \n
data_x2, data_y2, data_z2 \n
data_x3, data_y3, data_z3`

Comment: I'd say that's a bad idea. In that case, you'd probably be better off writing into a Database (which can be a single-file based one).

Comment: Or you pivot to write a line of Xs, then a line of Ys, then Zs ...

Comment: Okay thank you for sharing your insights with me. I'll think about it some more